# Carthage fails when trying to install FontAwesomeSwift in iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode7

I am trying to install FontAwesome.Swift in my Xcode project (Swift) so I created a Cartfile with the following line

```
github "thii/FontAwesome.swift" >= 0.4.1
```

as described here. Then I ran

carthage update and this happened :

```
==> carthage update
*** Fetching FontAwesome.swift
*** Checking out FontAwesome.swift at "0.6.0"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/fr/sn4l2f393_v_ytcwkb0lx7_40000gp/T/carthage-xcodebuild.4QnCto.log
*** Building scheme "FontAwesome" in FontAwesome.xcodeproj
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 <path_to_project>/<ProjectName>/Carthage/Checkouts/FontAwesome.swift/FontAwesome/FontAwesome.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
<path_to_project>/<ProjectName>/Carthage/Checkouts/FontAwesome.swift/FontAwesome/FontAwesome.swift:72:61: error: 'String.Index' does not have a member named 'advancedBy'
A shell task failed with exit code 65:
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 <path_to_project>/<ProjectName>/Carthage/Checkouts/FontAwesome.swift/FontAwesome/FontAwesome.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deduce from the error message:

> 'String.Index' does not have a member named 'advancedBy'

that you are still using Xcode 6.x? The `advancedBy` API is only available as of Swift 2.0 which ships with Xcode 7.

So, you have two options:

1. Upgrade your project to Xcode 7 / Swift 2.0
2. Edit your project's Cartfile so that it fetches a version of FontAwesome.swift that is compatible with you Xcode version. It seems FontAwesome.swift migrated to Swift 2.0 with version 0.6, so specifying a version < 0.6 (instead of >= 0.4.1) might do it.

In case you have both versions of Xcode installed, then Carthage may still use the command line tools from Xcode 6.x instead of the newer ones. You could fix this with the `xcodeselect` command in Terminal, but it's also possible to switch to the desired version of the tools in the Xcode Preferences (Locations tab).

Comment: Thanks for this. I fixed the issue by using xcode-select as follows ==> xcode-select -p
~/Developer/Xcode/Xcode_6_3/Xcode_6_3.app/Contents/Developer ==> sudo xcode-select -s ~/Developer/Xcode/Xcode_7_0/Xcode_7_0.app/Contents/Developer
Password:

Comment: After changing XCode Version, error removed from my side. Thanks